# Oracle graphics grant and revoke

Tags: oracle, graphics

I have an oracle graphics application that works with a 10G database, however with a 11G DB it doesnt as it refuses to see some tables in the DB, i think it has to do with privelages and roles.  Does anyone know how to grant roles in the graphics program.  I was thinking that at in the OPEN TRIGGER i can grant the tables to public , eg: GRANT ALTER, DELETE, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE ON GENDBA.SUPLOCATIONS TO PUBLIC; and in the close trigger i can revoke the grant therby retaining the security of the DB tables.

Can anyone out there help me?

Comment: What exactly is "*the graphics program*"?

Comment: thanks tbone.  what we have done is gotten scripts to block access to the database from toad , sqtools etc and all similar programs so users wouldnt be able to access the database (only given them forms access) and removed the passwords from all the tables.  well something like that and the graphics seem to work.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks tbone. what we have done is gotten scripts to block access to the database from toad , sqtools etc and all similar programs so users wouldnt be able to access the database (only given them forms access) and removed the passwords from all the tables. well something like that and the graphics seem to work. Thanks guys